# How to stop screen scrolling up while updating data in RecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView and some Views in it. They are being actualized every second. The problem is that, the screen is scrolling itself up(refreshing) every second, while user is scrolling down. How can I make it to hold position after data update?
This is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    initializeData();
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(offers);
    startCount();

}
private void startCount(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateData();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);


}
private void initializeData(){
    offers = new ArrayList<>();
    seconds = new ArrayList<>();
    seconds.add(600);
    seconds.add(10);
    seconds.add(20);
    offers.add(new Offer(seconds.get(0), R.drawable.zdj, 200));
    offers.add(new Offer(seconds.get(1), R.drawable.zdj));
    offers.add(new Offer(seconds.get(2), R.drawable.zdj));

}


private void updateData(){
    int i = 0;
    int tempSec;
    for(int j = 0; j < seconds.size();j++){

        tempSec = seconds.get(j);
        if(tempSec==0){
            offers.remove(j);
            seconds.remove(j);
            break;
        }
        tempSec--;
        seconds.set(j, tempSec);
        offers.set(j, new Offer(seconds.get(j), R.drawable.zdj));
    }
    initializeAdapter();
}
private void initializeAdapter() {

    adapter.notifyItemChanged(offers.size());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: why u want to stop scrolling if you can play with threads, Apply a parallel thread with it's main thread for loading data in recycler view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update the particular row of RecyclerView. Please use either of below overriden method as per your requirement,

```
notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)

notifyItemChanged(int position)
```

You can also set the particular position which position you want to show.